# Sequential has no attribute save_weights

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

Iam trying to load a pretrained model and save its weights .I am getting Attribue error.Here is my code.

```
import tensorflow as tf
model=tf.keras.models.load_model("mymodel.h5")
model.save_weights("hello.h5")
```

And i get an attribute error

```
model.save_wieghts("hello")

AttributeError: 'Sequential' object has no attribute 'save_wieghts'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your spelling, you've written 'save_wieghts' instead of 'save_weights'...